# EF Core Use .Include with Parent-Child-relation in same table

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

I have a table `[dbo].[Product]` like

```
ProductID | Description | OtherProductVariantID
```

where `OtherProductVariantID` is a `ProductID` of the **same table** and the corresponding Product entity

```
public class Product
{
        public int ProductID {get; set;}
        public string Description{get; set;}

        public int? OtherProductVariantID {get; set;}
        public virtual Product VariantProduct {get; set;}
        public virtual ICollection<Product> VariantProducts { get; set; }
}
```

And it is configured via Fluent-API like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>(entity =>
{
        entity.HasOne(d => d.VariantProduct)
                .WithMany(p => p.VariantProducts)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.OtherProductVariant)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Product_OtherProductVariant");
});
```

**[In human language]**

What I wanted is to load a Product entity with

```
var product = Context.Product
        .Include(p => p.VariantProduct)
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == 12345);
```

so that my VariantProduct is available for further processing, but it is always null.

What did I do wrong or is this somehow not possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's in your `OtherProductVariant` entity?

Comment: `VariantProduct` is the parent product entity , `VariantProducts` is your child products collection . Check your database tables to confirm that . Use like below to check both : var product = _context.Products
        .Include(p => p.VariantProducts).Include(p => p.VariantProduct)
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID ==12345);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution to your problem:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasOne(d => d.VariantProduct)
                .WithMany(p => p.VariantProducts)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.OtherProductVariantID )
                .HasPrincipalKey(x=> x.ProductId);
    });
```

this code worked well for me!

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.